# How to create a truth table for $p→(q→r)$

Tags: logic

**p→(q→r)**

---

I know how to create for 2 inputs using subset theorem, but have no idea how to create a truth table for 3 inputs.

Comment: The following site will generate a truth table: https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $3$ variables, each of which can be $T$ or $F$, you get $2\cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 8$ possible combinations, and thus $8$ rows in the truth-table. You can systematically get all those combinations by doing the following.

First, start with the right-most variable and alternate between $T$ and $F$:

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
p&q&r&p\to(q\to r)\\
\hline
&&T&\\
&&F&\\
&&T&\\
&&F&\\
&&T&\\
&&F&\\
&&T&\\
&&F&\\
\end{array}

Then take the variable to the left of it, and alternate every $2$:

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
p&q&r&p\to(q\to r)\\
\hline
&T&T&\\
&T&F&\\
&F&T&\\
&F&F&\\
&T&T&\\
&T&F&\\
&F&T&\\
&F&F&\\
\end{array}

Finally, alternate every $4$ for the last variable:

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
p&q&r&p\to(q\to r)\\
\hline
T&T&T&\\
T&T&F&\\
T&F&T&\\
T&F&F&\\
F&T&T&\\
F&T&F&\\
F&F&T&\\
F&F&F&\\
\end{array}

You can verify that these $8$ rows have all the $8$ different truth-value combinations.

OK, now, to evaluate the statement, we can do two different methods. Foirst, we can create a separate column for each component statement:

\begin{array}{ccc|c|c}
p&q&r&q \to r&p\to(q\to r)\\
\hline
T&T&T&T&T\\
T&T&F&F&F\\
T&F&T&T&T\\
T&F&F&T&T\\
F&T&T&T&T\\
F&T&F&F&T\\
F&F&T&T&T\\
F&F&F&T&T\\
\end{array}

Alternatively, we put the truth-values under the respective operators:

\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
p&q&r&p& \to & (q\to r)\\
\hline
T&T&T&&T&T\\
T&T&F&&F&F\\
T&F&T&&T&T\\
T&F&F&&T&T\\
F&T&T&&T&T\\
F&T&F&&T&F\\
F&F&T&&T&T\\
F&F&F&&T&T\\
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really comprehensive.

Comment: @AmateurAtAnything You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need 8 rows in the table, one for every possibility of $p, q, r$. After that make a column for $(q\rightarrow r)$ then use that column to make the column for $p\rightarrow(q\rightarrow r)$.